# How can I separately style CSS 'content' elements?

Tags: css

I have a nav list that looks like this:

Home  /  About  /  Locations  /  Contact

I'm coding it as a simple `<ul>` and using something like this for the separators:

```
#nav li:after {
    content: "/";
}
```

However... the designer wants the current page that you're on (the 'active' item in the nav) to be shown in bold and ask change to a different font. Something like this:

Home  /  **About**  /  Locations  /  Contact

This is easy enough to do with a separate style specifically for the active `<li>` item. However, here's the problem: the separator character ("/") also changes to bold and the new font, since it is considered to be part of the `<li>` item. This is bad... I want the separators to always look the same, regardless of which page is active. Is there a way to change that, or override the formatting on the separator? (Or a better way to code this with CSS that will accomplish what I'm trying to do?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell the `/` to have a normal font weight.

```css
#nav li:after {
    content: "/";
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Sigh. Sometimes the simplest answer is the right answer. Can't believe I didn't figure this out myself. :-) Thank you!

Comment: @Eric, Ha ha. Happens to all of us :)

Comment: This answer does not address the issue of “the new font”. Presumably there is a `font-family` setting for the “active” item (which is poor typography), and it that case, the rule for `:after` should contain an explicit `font-family` setting that matches the one set for the list.